# Ubuntu desktop not responsive programs take ages to launch when clicked. Aspire One Happy notebook

Tags: wubi, acer, aspire

I have done a few updates on Ubuntu 12.04 which was installed via the WUBI installer.
The Aspire One Happy notebook dual boots with Windows 7 Basic.
Now Ubuntu desktop not responsive programs take ages to launch when clicked.

I have checked the drivers with jockey and all seems OK.
I've also installed other desktop managers, like Xubuntu and KDE and tried gnome classic.
No matter what I use. it's the same sluggish response.

Aspire One Happy notebook Specs.

CPU~Single core Intel Atom CPU N450 (-HT-) clocked at Min:1000.000Mhz Max:1666.000Mhz 
Kernel~3.2.0-29-generic i686 Up~20 min Mem~569.0/991.0MB HDD~250.1GB(45.3% used) 
Procs~160 Client~Shell inxi~1.8.4

Graphics:
Card: Intel N10 Family Integrated Graphics Controller 
X.Org: 1.11.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1024x600@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel IGD x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version: 1.4 Mesa 8.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For notebook like this i don't recommend Wubi. If you install Ubuntu with Wubi there is huge performance drop. I recommend installing native Ubuntu(Not with Wubi).

Comment: Thank you, thought that maybe the case, did not expect that much of a performance drop though. Well a back up and partition coming up then I guess for a real dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  To fix it, switch from Wubi to a native installation.

To see what's going on, open a terminal shell (`Ctrl+Alt+t`) and run top (type `top` and press `Enter`).  This will give you a live display of what's using the system resources.  When your system slows down, you should see that a process called `mount.ntfs` is using 99% of the CPU.  `mount.ntfs` is the driver that Wubi uses to access the underlying Windows filesystem and, as you can see, this is what's slowing things down.

Another thing you can try is upgrading the RAM.  The reason you're using the HDD so much is that, with just 1 GB, the system has to spend a lot of time moving data between RAM and HDD.  It's this combination of poor HDD performance and lack of RAM that is really killing performance.